# Show the tooltip in the list box selected value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I show the title or tooltip when the mouse on the list box value, as in the following picture?

[image].

Comment: Are you having trouble with any code, or are you just looking for a generalized solution?

Comment: i dont have any model, but i have some open source jquery snippet, that are depend more then three include, i guess there is a jquery function, with that we can do the jquery tool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see example::

```
<!-- Include custom code to handle the tooltip -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  //After loading the page insert the title attribute.
  $(function(){
    $("select option").attr( "title", "" );
    $("select option").each(function(i){
      this.title = this.text;
    })
  });

  //Attach a tooltip to select elements
  $("select").tooltip({
   left: 25
  });
</script>

<!-- When moving the mouse over the below options -->
<select>
   <option>very long option text 1</option>
   <option>very long option text 2</option>
   <option>very long option text 3</option>
   <option>very long option text 4</option>
   <option>very long option text 5</option>
   <option>very long option text 6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The above wasn't too intuitive for me, since it just shows the same text for the tooltip.  What worked for me, was to sneak id as the very long tooltip text, replace 'very long option text' with the normal select combo box value, and replace `this.title = this.text` with `this.title = this.id`.  I also didn't need the attach tooltip part, although I guess that might help choose where it's placed (which by default seems fine).

Answer (score -1):

html:

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(event) {
    $('#sel').mouseenter(function(e) {
        this.title = $("#sel option:selected" ).text();
    });
});
```